# Add files to VCS Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, kotlin, github

I want to upload my project on GitHub and first time I ran into the problem. When I try to add do right click on project/Git/Add I get the message. What can it be?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FwTU.png)

Comment: This is the old line-breaks problem: https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/crlf-vs-lf-normalizing-line-endings-in-git/

Comment: Also as a side note you probably shouldn't be checking your gradle caches into version control...

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I've already fixed the problem. If it's interesting for you, you can find a solution bellow.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a conflict of android studio's versions. I updated it but something went wrong and now there were many small problems. I definitely cleaned android studio and all its options and downloaded it again and now it works perfect!